# turn a 16:9 monitor into a 16:10 monitor

Tags: display, resolution, aspect-ratio

The monitor in question is an Acer V233HL bd. I need to use an Android dongle with it (got no other native 16:10 screens to work with). Sorry if this is not the appropriate area to ask, could not find any other more relevant among the stack exchange websites. So what I would want is to change the monitor's ROM or something similar (i.e.make sure the resolution change is memorized by the monitor itself, and not just in the computer OS resolution). Thanks!

Comment: As you cannot add 120 pixels to the vertical height of the monitor, perhaps you could force yourself to not use 192 pixels from, say, the right edge. You will then be using a 16:10 monitor ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the EDID, but most likely it must be hardware-compatible, meaning the aspect ratio will have to be respected.

The EDID contains the name and specifications of the monitor's technical data including it's capabilities (res, refresh).

The EDID can be re-written using special software.

Theres a python script called edid-rw that can be found at GitHub.

It reads / writes EDID data on the i2c channel between the PC and monitor.

The only way to see if you can actually use a different aspect ratio is to test by changing the EDID; but if it works the image will be distorted since one ratio will be altered to fit another.

Answer (score 1):

An [Acer V233HL](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/professional-model-datasheet/UM.VV6AA.C02) has native resolution of 1920 x 1080 which is 16:9, not 16:10. Even if you were able to modify the firmware, it still wouldn't turn it into a 16:10 monitor due to physical limitations in [TN panels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film-transistor_liquid-crystal_display#Twisted_nematic_.28TN.29).